# C# datagridview filter on DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checked or unchecked

Tags: c#, datagrid

The dataset contains a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn and i whould like to filter the view on 3 possibilities: show all(checkbox checked and unchecked) show only checked and only unchecked

```
 private void listBoxBehandeld_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string listBoxValue = "Alle";
            listBoxValue = listBoxBehandeld.GetItemText(listBoxBehandeld.SelectedItem);


        switch (listBoxValue)
        {
            case "Alle":
               //Show checked and unchecked


                break;

            case "Ja":
               //show checked            



                break;

            case "Nee":
                //show unchecked
                }
                break;
        }
        dataGridView.DataSource = meldingenBindingSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enumerate the rows in the grid to filter based on your case selection.

There's an example from
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/74df79a9-87ad-4cec-8502-3a357015558d/how-to-check-the-datagridviewcheckboxcolumn-if-its-checked-?forum=winforms

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
{
   //Get the appropriate cell using index, name or whatever and cast to DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
   DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells[colCheck] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

   //Compare to the true value because Value isn't boolean
   if (cell.Value == cell.TrueValue)
      //The value is true
}
```